# Number of paths for random walk with n steps and an absorbing barrier at -1

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-walk

I have a random walker that starts at $x = 0$. They can step either left or right one unit. However, if they reach $x = -1$ they fall off a cliff (say), so those paths are invalid -- I've heard this called an absorbing barrier. How do I count the number of possible valid paths if the walker has taken $n$ steps?

As a bonus question, how can I count the number of valid paths which end at $x  =0$?

Comment: I believe this is the same as *the ballot problem*. In a two-candidate election where ballots are counted one at a time and the election ends in a tie, how many ways are there for Candidate 1 never to be behind? Since the answer grows very fast as a function of $n$, I'm not sure what you mean by calculating (as opposed to enumerating) all valid paths ending at $x=0$. If you really want to list them all, I'd say that's a programming question more than a mathematical one, and surely there's some simple backtracking algorithm to do it.

Comment: See, e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/338561/whats-the-probability-that-a-always-leads-b-in-the-process-of-counting-vote

Comment: @GerryMyerson thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for. I edited the question to reflect that I'm wanting to count all of the paths, rather than "calculate" them.

Comment: A relevant proof of the generalized ballot theorem is given with [this link](https://www-users.math.umn.edu/~reiner/Classes/Four_Proofs_of_Ballot_Theorem.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{array}{|r|c|c|}
\hline
&\text{Without absorbing barrier}&\text{With absorbing barrier at $-1$}
\\\hline
\text{Number of paths of length $n$}&2^n&\displaystyle\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}
\\\hline
\text{Number of paths of length $n$ ending at $0$*}&\displaystyle\binom{n}{n/2}&\displaystyle\frac1{n/2+1}\binom{n}{n/2}
\\\hline
\end{array}$$
${}^*$Assuming $n$ is even.

I present the data this way to highlight the strange coincidence that the lower left entry and the upper right entry are the same (when $n$ is even).